# Showing WooCommerce variation image inside slick slide with thumbs

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, slider

Is there a way to insert the variation_image into the slick slider and the thumbs?
I am attaching the code for AJAX:

```
function wordpress_ajax_select_variation()
{
    $status = "failed";
    $stock = "out_of_stock";
    $selected_variation = array();
    $variation_id = 0;
    $variation_price = 0;
    $variation_image = '';

    $product_id = absint($_POST['product_id']);
    $_post_variations = $_POST['variations'];

    $post_variations = explode("|", $_post_variations);
    foreach ($post_variations as $var) {
        list($att_name, $att_id) = explode("=", $var);
        $att_name = str_replace("attribute_", "", $att_name);
        $selected_variation[$att_name] = $att_id;
    }

    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $variation_ids = $product->get_children();

    foreach ($variation_ids as $variation_id) {
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id);
        $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();

        $check = 0;
        foreach ($attributes as $k => $v) {
            if ($selected_variation[$k] != $v) {
                $check++;
            }
        }

        if ($check == 0) {
            $stock = $variation->get_stock_status();
            $variation_image = $variation->get_image('full');
            $variation_price = $variation->get_price_html();
            $status = "done";
            break;
        }
    }

    echo wp_send_json(array("status" => $status, "variation_id" => $variation_id, "variation_price" => $variation_price, "stock" => $stock, "variation_image" => $variation_image));

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_wordpress_ajax_select_variation', 'wordpress_ajax_select_variation');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wordpress_ajax_select_variation', 'wordpress_ajax_select_variation');
```

This code helps me to get a variation id through AJAX, with the help of which I generate the price, image, etc.

This is my AJAX Javascript to get the variation_image that I need to display in my template:

```
  function handleAttributeSelection() {
    //Init variations
    let variations = [];

    let product_id = $('form.cubestheme-add-to-cart-form')
      .find("input[name='product_id']")
      .val();
    let product_type = $('form.cubestheme-add-to-cart-form')
      .find("input[name='product_type']")
      .val();

    if (product_type == 'variable') {
      let selectedVariation = true;

      $('.attribute_box').each(function () {
        let att_id = $(this).find('.single-term.active').data('attr-id');
        if (typeof att_id !== 'undefined') {
          let att_name = $(this).find('.single-term.active').data('attr-name');
          let att_slug = $(this).find('.single-term.active').data('attr-slug');
          variations.push(att_name + '=' + att_slug);
        } else {
          selectedVariation = false;
        }
      });

      if (!selectedVariation) {
        //$("#warning-modal").fadeIn();
        return;
      } else {
        //Get Variation ID
        let data = {
          action: 'wordpress_ajax_select_variation',
          product_id: product_id,
          variations: variations.join('|'),
        };

        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
          data: data,
          beforeSend: function (response) {
            $('.se-pre-con').fadeIn('fast');
          },
          complete: function (response) {
            $('.se-pre-con').fadeOut('show');
          },
          success: function (response) {
            if (response.error & response.product_url) {
              window.location = response.product_url;
              return;
            } else {
              if (response.stock == 'instock') {
                $('form.cubestheme-add-to-cart-form')
                  .find("input[name='variation_id']")
                  .val(response.variation_id);
              } else {
                $('#warning-modal h4').html(
                  'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.'
                );
                $('#warning-modal').fadeIn();
                return;
              }

              $('.single-product-small-wrapper .slick-track').append(`
                <div class="small-img-wrapper">
                  <figure class="img-placeholder">
                    ${response.variation_image}
                  </figure>
                  </div>
                `);

              $('.single-product-big-wrapper .slick-track').append(`
                <div class="big-img-wrapper mouseover">
                  <figure class="img-placeholder">
                    ${response.variation_image}
                  </figure>
                  </div>
                `);

              $('.single-product-small-wrapper').slick('refresh');
              $('.single-product-big-wrapper').slick('refresh');
            }
          },
        });
      }
    } else {
      form.submit();
    }
  }
```

I've tried everything, including appending the slider and refreshing it, I don't even know what I've tried and I've never been able to do what I want. And I want the image in the thumb and the large image to be displayed, and when I change the variation (if that variation does not have an image), I will not be shown the image from the last variation.

This is my PHP partial where i display product images with thumbs:

```
<?php

/**
 * Single Product Image
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 7.8.0
 */

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

// Note: `wc_get_gallery_image_html` was added in WC 3.3.2 and did not exist prior. This check protects against theme overrides being used on older versions of WC.
if (!function_exists('wc_get_gallery_image_html')) {
    return;
}

global $product;
$product_id    = $product->get_id();
$mainImage     = $product->get_image_id();
$galleryImages = $product->get_gallery_image_ids();




?>


<div class="single-product-slider">
    <?php
    if (!empty($mainImage)) {
    ?>
        <div class="single-product-small-wrapper"><!-- small img start -->

            <?php
            if (empty($product->get_image_id())) :
            ?>
                <div class="small-img-wrapper">
                    <figure class="img-placeholder">
                        <?php echo wc_placeholder_img('full'); ?>
                    </figure>
                </div>
            <?php

            else :
            ?>
                <div class="small-img-wrapper">
                    <figure class="img-placeholder">
                        <img src="<?php echo !empty($variation_image) ? $variation_image : wp_get_attachment_image_url($mainImage, 'full') ?>" alt="image">
                    </figure>
                </div>
            <?php
            endif;
            ?>

            <?php
            if (!empty($galleryImages && $product->get_image_id())) {
                foreach ($galleryImages as $attachment_id) {
            ?>
                    <div class="small-img-wrapper">
                        <figure class="img-placeholder">
                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, "full"); ?>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <!-- small img end -->
        <div class="single-product-big-wrapper zoom-wrapper"><!-- big img start -->

            <div class="big-img-wrapper mouseover">
                <?php
                if (empty($product->get_image_id())) :
                ?>
                    <figure class="img-placeholder">
                        <?php
                        echo wc_placeholder_img('full');
                        ?>
                    </figure>
                <?php

                else :
                ?>
                    <figure class="img-placeholder">
                        <img src="<?php echo !empty($variation_image) ? $variation_image : wp_get_attachment_image_url($mainImage, 'full') ?>" alt="">
                    </figure>
                <?php
                endif;
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
            if ($galleryImages && $product->get_image_id()) {
                foreach ($galleryImages as $attachment_id) {
            ?>
                    <div class="big-img-wrapper mouseover">
                        <figure class="img-placeholder">
                            <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, "full"); ?>
                        </figure>
                    </div>
            <?php }
            } ?>

        </div>
        <!-- big img end -->
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should modify your AJAX success function to clear existing images and add new variation images to the slider each time a variation is selected and then ensure that your PHP template initially loads all potential images for the product and its variations. Also, within your AJAX function, remove the old images from the slider and append the new variation image, followed by refreshing the slider to update its view. Confirm that the image URLs for variations are correctly retrieved and sent to the AJAX function